# Графическая библиотека для визуализации бинарного дерева поиска

Tags: c++, графика, бинарное-дерево, визуализация

Моя задача - визуализировать бинарное дерево поиска средствами C++ и поддерживаемых языком графических библиотек.

Размер входных данных заранее неизвестен (может быть как дерево из 4-5 узлов, так и из пары сотен или больше), соответственно, на ум приходит идея о том, что сначала дерево рисуется в таком размере, чтобы оно умещалось на экране, а после этого, при желании пользователь мог увеличить/уменьшить изображение, чтобы рассмотреть нужные ему ноды.

Само дерево уже реализовано, осталась только визуализация. Хочется получить что-то наподобие [этого](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BST.html) (хотя бы частично - сначала просто отрисовка дерева любого размера, а остальные фичи уже после).

Собственно, вопрос - какую лучше библиотеку использовать для такого рода задач, и, может, имеются какие-либо простейшие примеры?

Comment: А просто нарисовать кружочки-стрелочки у Вас получается?

Comment: @KoVadim, пару раз писал небольшие графические программки на SDL и прошел туториал по opengl (самые основы). У меня просто опыта в графике кроме этого вообще никакого, я и выбрать не могу ничего, так как не знаю, что лучше будет для такой задачи.

Comment: Так что кружочки/стрелочки в принципе могу рисовать.

Comment: Если дерево бинарное, то его достаточно легко нарисовать - на каждом уровне будет ровно 2 в степени (уровень - 1) "кружочков" (кроме последнего. Там может быть меньше). Собственно, что бы такое дерево нарисовать, нужно только знать общее кол-во элементов.

Другое дело - рисовать произвольные деревья. Тут применяют обычно рекурсивный алгоритм. То есть - нарисовать дерево - это нарисовать ноду и два поддерева.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно порекомендовать использовать фреймворк Qt. В примерах имеется проект, как мне кажется, аккурат по теме. Называется [Elastic Nodes Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-example.html):

[image: Elastic Nodes Example]

Принцип действия прост: сначала для каждого узла (шарика) рассчитывается сила отталкивания от всех иных узлов, а затем наоборот - сила притяжения, зависящая от числа связей узла с другими. Всё это уже анимировано и автоматически расползается, выдавая иногда довольно замысловатые картины:

[image: Пример графа]